# Dell Optiplex GX620 second DVD drive

Tags: dvd, optical-drive

I have a NEC ND-3540A DVD drive and I wanted it as a second drive. I hooked up its power supply and IO Bus like the primary drive. They would be connected by the same wire. In the BIOS when both are connected it says some gibberish on the master and it says nothing is connected in the slave. Once I take out the NEC drive the bios finds the primary (which is a Sony) perfectly.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparewntly this is a dribe with an ATAPI interface. Aka ATA or PATA..

These drives are old. They are from the time when we moved from PC's with a harddisk controller and a harddisk to a harddisk with withs controller integrated on the drive. (aka **I**ntergated **D**rive **E**lectronics). The harddisks come with an interface which can directly connect to an AT (80286-based PC)'s AT bus. Hence it is also called **AT** **ATachement**.

You can connect a single drive to such an PATA bus. If you connect two drives then you have two controllers in a fight. Therefor sings settles on these three conditions:

1. A single device. Set to **single**
2. Two devices. One set so **master** (which means single + comtrol a secondary device).
3. Two devices. One set to ** slave** (which means there is another device set to master and that you need to listen to it. Do not use the controller on this device.

ATAPI (AT packet interface) follows this sequence. This way you can add a CDROM or a DVDROM to an AT bus.

> I hooked up its power supply and IO Bus like the primary drive.

so this is wrong. You need to add it as a slave. Else you have two controllers fighting over the bus.

Either you have:

- One drive in **single** mode. (sometimes jumpered as single/master).
- or two drives. One as master and one as slave.

The way I raised your post you have a single drive as master or as slave. And you added a second master.  This will not work.

Comment: BIOS found it properly. Now I need drivers for it. Wish me luck finding them!